# Is it possible to ignore pyright checking for one line?

Tags: python, pyright

I need to ignore pyright checking for one line. Is there any special comment for it?

```
def create_slog(group: SLogGroup, data: Optional[dict] = None):
    SLog.insert_one(SLog(group=group, data=data))  # pyright: disable
```

`# pyright: disable` -- doesn't work

Comment: Pyright isn't something I know much about, but https://github.com/Microsoft/pyright/issues/108 seems to have some interesting proposed ideas.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Yes it is with "# type: ignore", for example:

```
try:
    return int(maybe_digits_string)    # type: ignore
except Exception:
    return None
```

Comment: Also, `# type: ignore` is standard and other equivalent checkers will also respect it, so it's definitely the way to go. 

Comment: I have a situation where `mypy` understands my annotation correctly, but `pyright` doesn't.  Is there a way to have a directive only for `pyright`?  I guess  the real resolution is to file a bug report for pyright.

Comment: is there anything that can be applied to a block of code rather than a single line?

Answer (score 53):

As mentioned in the accepted answer, using a `# type: ignore` comment is effective.

```py
foo: int = "123"  # type: ignore
```

But, as mentioned in that answer's comments, using `# type: ignore` can collide with other type checkers (such as mypy). To work around this, Pyright now supports `# pyright: ignore` comments (which mypy will not pick up on). This is documented [here](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/blob/main/docs/comments.md#line-level-diagnostic-suppression).

```py
foo: int = "123"  # pyright: ignore
```

A `pyright: ignore` comment can be followed by a comma-delimited list of specific pyright rules that should be ignored:

```
foo: int = "123"  # pyright: ignore [reportPrivateUsage, reportGeneralTypeIssues]
```

Meanwhile, adding the following comment to the top of your module will disable checking of the listed rules for **the whole file**:

```
# pyright: reportUndefinedVariable=false, reportGeneralTypeIssues=false
```

The [pyright docs on comments](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/blob/1f42e17eb3a036271dd17b79a7eb5593c10aae46/docs/comments.md) say "typically this comment is placed at or near the top of a code file on its own line."

Comment: Couldn't I use this in the `pyrightconfig.json` file?

Comment: I think so. See [the pyright docs on configuration](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/blob/1f42e17eb3a036271dd17b79a7eb5593c10aae46/docs/configuration.md), specifically the `ignore` option.

Comment: actually I checked out their gh issues and found out that atm they [do not intend](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/issues/3198#issuecomment-1068475439) to implement this

Comment: weirdly, this ignores the whole file :/