# How do you ignore specific Pyright type checks by project, file, line?

Tags: python, pyright

I cannot quite find clear documentation on how to ignore one or more specific [Pyright](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright) checks:

1. Using a config file at the root of your project.
2. At the top of a file, function, or method.
3. Each ligne as a trailing comment.

Thanks in advance for sharing this information.

Comment: Did you check out the configuration documentation?

Comment: The usual `mypy` in-line comments should work, and for `pyright` specific config, you can put a `pyrightconfig.json` in your project root.  You can find available config options [here](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/blob/main/docs/configuration.md#type-check-diagnostics-settings).

Comment: @gshpychka it does cover the config file at the root of your project, but not my two other bullets as far as I could tell.

Comment: Thanks, @suvayu, could you post an example of the exact syntax for the mypy directives?

Comment: I added my comment along with the example you asked for as an answer. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The usual mypy in-line comments like `# type: ignore` should work ([see details](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/error_codes.html)), and for `pyright` specific config, you can put a `pyrightconfig.json` in your project root. You can find available config options [here](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/blob/main/docs/configuration.md#type-check-diagnostics-settings).  It's just a JSON file, so it looks something like this:

```
{
    "venvPath": "/home/username/.virtualenvs/",
    "venv": "myenv",
    "reportOptionalSubscript": false,
    "reportOptionalMemberAccess": false
}
```

**EDIT:**

In-source configuration can be as type-ignore statements as supported by `mypy`.  `# type: ignore` is not a place holder for something else, it is literal. To narrow it down and ignore a specific error (it can be only one of the `mypy` error codes), like this: `# type: ignore[error-code]`

To use the specific example of `import` mentioned in the comments, here are the two variants:

```
from os import non_existent  # type: ignore[attr-defined]

from missing_module import name  # type: ignore
```

This is all discussed in the link to the `mypy` docs I provided, and the [list of error codes](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/error_code_list.html) linked from there.

`pyright` specific configuration <s>can only be project wide</s> (see **EDIT3**), either by specifying them in a `[tool.pyright]` section in your `pyproject.toml` file, or by creating a `pyrightconfig.json` like above in your top-level project directory.

**EDIT2:**

In the comments the OP raised the question how to find the mypy error-codes that correspond to a pyright config option.  Unfortunately there's no easy way besides reading the docs thoroughly along with some understanding of the language; e.g. in the case of `from os import name`, Python is actually importing the attribute `os.name` of the module object `os` into the current namespace.  The following interactive session should make this clear:

```
In [1]: import os

In [2]: type(os)
Out[2]: module

In [3]: locals()["curdir"]
-------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-a31c5782bef1> in <module>
----> 1 locals()["curdir"]

KeyError: 'curdir'

In [4]: from os import curdir

In [5]: locals()["curdir"]
Out[5]: '.'

In [6]: os.curdir == curdir
Out[6]: True
```

**EDIT3**:

Pyright also seems to support file-level, and line-level directives, [the documentation is hidden under "comments"](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/blob/main/docs/comments.md). In short, you can ask pyright to ignore a line or ignore specific pyright errors like this:

```py
import missing_module import name # pyright: ignore
import missing_module import name # pyright: ignore[reportMissingImports]
```

You can find the list of errors in the [configuration docs](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/blob/main/docs/configuration.md).

Comment: Thanks, @suvayu. I tried the suggested template for single-line ignores. The line `from absent_package import absent_module  # reportMissingImports: ignore` won't work for me. Context SublimeText 4 with LSP-pyright extension.

Comment: @DouglasLassance You misunderstood what I wrote.  for in-source comments, you have to use type-ignore statements as supported by `mypy` (the 1st link), and pyright specific options can only be configured project wide in the configuration file, the available options for which are in the 2nd link.

Comment: Thanks, @suvayu. It was not clear out the bat that for suppressing Pyright messages I had to use Mypy codes. Is there a reliable way to find the equivalence. How does one go from `reportMissingImports` to `attr-defined`?

Comment: @DouglasLassance unfortunately no easy way, I added some explanation in my answer, hopefully that makes it clear how I arrived at that conclusion.

Comment: **This answer is *absolutely* untrue.** Pyright provides a pyright-specific `# pyright: ignore[...]` comment pragma for ignoring pyright-specific error codes on a line-by-line basis (e.g., `# pyright: ignore[reportOptionalMemberAccess]`). See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70513059/2809027) and [this related StackOverflow answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72322304/2809027).

Comment: @CecilCurry I have updated my answer, can we tone down the hyperbole now?

Answer (score 1):

You can ignore the types for an entire file by placing `#type: ignore` at the start of the file.