# How to show and ignore Pyright error codes

Tags: python-typing, pylance, pyright

I am using pyright type checker and need to suppress warnings where e.g. numpy type stubs are insufficient to infer correct types. This can be accomplished with `#type: ignore` comment. However, I'd like any other issue to still be highlighted on the same line. For example `mypy` offers `show_error_codes` option that gives error codes that I can append to type:ignore comment to have only this specific issue suppressed.

I couldn't find such option in the docs https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/blob/main/docs/configuration.md . Is it possible to have specific error codes shown / ignored with pyright?

Answer (score 4):

I just found out how to do that in both Pyright and Pylance.

When you run pyright it should give a detailed error report and show the corresponding diagnostic type, such as *reportOptionalMemberAccess* or *reportOptionalSubscript*. Same can be achieved by looking through the diagnostics reported by the language server (LSP).

You can then annotate the line with `# pyright: ignore[reportOptionalMemberAccess]` to disable this type of diagnostic.

Comment: see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68446642/how-do-i-get-pylance-to-ignore-the-possibility-of-none